# Missing assembly after declaring log4net ILog

Tags: .net, log4net

I have a test project using Log4net.

When I add a class library (from a project in the same solution) this library works fine.

When adding a reference to the log4net assembly nothing changes,but as soon as I start using the assembly by defining an ILog the projects doen't recognize the classlibrary as well as the log4net assembly any more.

What am I missing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Right click your project -> Select properties -> Select Application 
   if your target framework is set to .NET Framework 4 Client Profile, change it to .NET Framework 4 because some DLLs doesn't run with Client Profile which is light weighted.

Thanks and Regards,
Venkatarajan Arthanari